# IE9+ placeholder AngularJS (no jQuery)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, placeholder

I found this: https://gist.github.com/thomseddon/4703810

I was reading the comments and there are a few things wrong with it. Has anyone in the angularjs mix come up with a valid way of placing placeholders with the help of angularjs?

It's not a requirements to use angularjs in my case, if it helps though! Otherwise I'd look at pure javascript options.

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to search for the element's ".closest('form')" and bind to submit events.. if you're using a validation framework, you'll need to bind to its' events as well.

Honestly, I wouldn't worry about IE < 11 support, [they're really waning at this point](http://www.sitepoint.com/browser-trends-november-2015-chrome-clinch/), and IE8 is all but dead in the water with changes to HTTPS being made globally (deprecating old protocol version and higher risk ciphers).  IE11 will be around for a while with Windows 7 hold outs.  The only real down side is you can't universally use a conditional comment that includes IE10 to notify users to upgrade/change browsers.